# On Scaling the Contents of a Minipage

Tags: minipage, scaling, includegraphics, scale

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{scalerel,scalefnt}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}

\textwidth=4in
\textheight=6.40in
\voffset -7pt

\begin{document}
\vspace*{55pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{3.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
{\scalefont{3.35}\textbf{MY TITLE}}\vspace*{20pt}

{\scalefont{1.35}{\textit{\textbf{with}}}}\vspace*{20pt}

{\vstretch{2.15}{\scalefont{1.25}{\textbf{A \, S u b t i t l e}}}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I scale the contents of the above minipage? Is there a way to employ some dort of a scaling factor? I tried an approach analogous to the way one would scale an `\includegraphics` image, but that does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: exactly as graphics `\scalebox{.01}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}.....\end{minipage}}`

Comment: Many thanks @DavidCarlisle. I had thought perhaps something along the lines of `\includegraphics[scale= ]`.

Comment: that (usually) just calls `\scalebox` in the backgroud for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exactly as graphics

```
\scalebox{.01}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}.....\end{minipage}}
```

Comment: Thanks again David Carlisle.